# Index of the current row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 DataGridViews and I transfer data between them. My question is: How can i move the index of datagridview1 row to next one after the data has been transfered.

Code:

```
int index = 0;
int index1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < produseDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex; i++)
     index = produseDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["dprodus"].RowIndex;
for (int j = 0; j < produse_magazinDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index; j++)
     index1 = produse_magazinDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells["produs"].RowIndex;
     produseDataGridView.CurrentCell = produseDataGridView.Rows[index + 1].Cells[0];
     produse_magazinDataGridView.CurrentCell = produse_magazinDataGridView.Rows[index1 + 1].Cells[0];
```

Comment: so when you transfer the data you want it in the exact same position?

Comment: i want it to move in next position!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "how can i move the index of datagridview1 row to next".

Index is just a integer in your code. If you meant to write "how to select the next row" then its:

```
produseDataGridView.Rows(Index + 1).Selected = True;
produse_magazinDataGridView.Rows(Index1 + 1).Selected = True;
```